# Silly Sven Paints a Highway

Tags: mathematics

Sven got a job painting the yellow midline on a 50 mile road. The more he paints, the slower he progresses, since he keeps getting further away from the paint can!

To be exact, if he has already painted $m$ miles at the beginning of a day, then he will paint $(1/2)^m$ more miles that day. For example, on the first day, he hasn't painted anything yet, so he paints $(1/2)^0=1$ mile that day. The next day, he paints $(1/2)^1=0.5$ miles.

Will he ever finish?

---

<sup>(I promise that this can be solved without using any complicated formulas or concepts!)</sup>

Comment: Silly Sven?  I thought he was called [Shlemiel...](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sven will

> Eventually finish

Proof:

> Every day that he has previously covered less than 50 miles, he will paint more than $\frac{1}{2}^{50}$ miles. This will eventually sum to more than 50 miles. (Indeed, it is unbounded and Sven will eventually paint any finite length)

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't matter how slowly Sven paints - he will finish. In particular, consider the function $f(m)$ which takes the number of miles he started with as input and outputs the number of miles he finishes with. Notice that he starts with $0$ miles painted, then has $f(0)$ miles painted, then $f(f(0))$ and then $f(f(f(0)))$. Notating the iteration of $f$ as $$f^n(x)=\underbrace{f(f(\ldots f}_{n \text{ repetitions}}(x)\ldots ))$$
we may find that, so long as $f(m)>m$ (i.e. he always paints something) and $f$ is continuous, we can conclude:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f^n(0)=\infty$$
which means that the amount he's painted after $n$ days goes to infinity with $n$. In particular, from the definition of a limit, this means that for any finite $M$, he will, in a finite amount of time, paint $M$ miles. This has a simple argument by contradiction - suppose that above limit were a finite $x$. Then
$$x=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f^n(0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f^{n+1}(0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(f^{n}(x))=f(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f^{n}(0))=f(x)$$
which contradicts the hypothesis that $f(x)>x$.

(One may also use the continuity of $f$ to use the extreme value theorem on $f(x)-x$ over the compact domain $[0,50]$, which generalizes @frodoskywalker's answer. Another curiosity is that if we weaken to requiring $f(x)\geq x$, then the given limit will tend towards the first fixed point of $f$ higher than $0$ - and, in fact, this is basically what we've done when we extend $f$ to the extended reals)

Answer (score 5):

I am going to dissent and say he the majority opinion here:

> While the series diverges, Sven dead. Very dead. EXTREMELY DEAD. To paint the last mile will take a minimum of 2^49 days. This is roughly One-Half Billion Million days. This is to a rough approximation One trillion years. The universe is less than 20 billion years old. So 50 Universe lives (so far) to paint. I mean sven sound like a strong fellow, but come on. The Sun is dead. Everyone he knows is dead. The paint he already did probably got destroyed when our sun exploded. 5/10 would not hire again (He did get the first half done mighty quick).

Comment: You've got me there, though I did tag the puzzle [math] instead of [physics] or [biology] !

Comment: "He did get the first half done might quick" Taking 132,000 years for $25$ miles is quick now? (Faster than some roadwork I've seen, but *still*)

Answer (score 0):

The one above is a better answer, but I hope this is also acceptable:

> All $m$ lengths are bound to be equal to or less than 1, because $1/2^m$ can only equal 1 if $m$ is 0, which can't be true save for the first day, making the next one ($1/2^m$) greater than 1/2. Which means all the $m$s starting with the third one are greater than 1/2. Therefore he'll eventually finish the work.